# Porcelain brush pen does not stick to ceramic ring

Tags: paint, ceramics

I painted a ceramic ring ([this](https://www.lespoulettes-bijoux.fr/bagues-fantaisie/femme-bague-anneau-de-ceramique-blanche-3mm-12985.html)) with porcelain pens ([edding 4200 porcelain brush pen](https://www.edding.com/products/edding-4200-porcelain-brush-pen/)). I followed the instructions of the pens:

- Clean the surface of the ring and remove dirt and grease.
- Apply the paint
- Allow the paint to dry for 15 minutes.
- Bake in the oven at 160°C

Nevertheless, the paint is not firm, can be easily removed with a finger and does not withstand daily use.

What can I do to permanently apply the paint to the ring? Are there other pens that hold better or a varnish that I can apply over the paint?

Comment: Maybe it's not getting enough time to cure? Bake it instead at 180°C for 30 minutes and let it cool in the oven before taking it out to avoid cracks.. Also, I have used acrylics to paint ceramic and then baked them to cure the paint. It didn't wash off even with scrubbing.

Answer (score 3):

From the "usage" section of the pen website (my emphasis):

> Daily cleaning: *avoid friction, rubbing and scrubbing* by positioning the item in the dishwasher so that it is not in contact with other items of crockery or cutlery

These pens are listed as decorative. You are not going to get a permanent bond that is as strong as the original ceramic finish. I am sure if you were to paint and fire the decorations, and then set them on display where they cannot be rubbed or scraped against things, the paint will hold up fine.

If you wanted to get a permanent finish as durable as the original material you would have to reglaze the item using porcelain glaze and a kiln capable of extremely high temperatures, between 2381℉ and 2455℉ (1305℃ and 1346℃).

[(source)](https://www.soulceramics.com/pages/slow-firing-porcelain)